# Why doesn't the BCL have CRC classes?

Tags: .net, base-class-library

Why doesn't the .NET Base Class Libary have CRC classes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eric Lippert has the best explanation of "Why Feature X is not implemented" (I think he knows a thing or two about why or why not things get implemented in the language)

> I am asked "why doesn't C# implement
>   feature X?" all the time. The answer
>   is always the same: because no one
>   ever designed, specified, implemented,
>   tested, documented and shipped that
>   feature. All six of those things are
>   necessary to make a feature happen.
>   All of them cost huge amounts of time,
>   effort and money. Features are not
>   cheap, and we try very hard to make
>   sure that we are only shipping those
>   features which give the best possible
>   benefits to our users given our
>   constrained time, effort and money
>   budgets.

From here (unreleated topic but relevant answer): http://web.archive.org/web/20140414043740/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx

Comment: Thanks microsoft for breaking their links as usual, here is a link to the archived version : http://web.archive.org/web/20140414043740/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx

Comment: @Pac0 Edited the answer with the archived link

Answer (score 1):

There are well-established algorithms for these (and CRC are also relatively simple to implement compared to encryption) and many open implementations to choose from.

http://tomkaminski.com/crc32-hashalgorithm-c-net